# Pybind11, how to invoke the __repr__ of an object within a std::vector?

Tags: pybind11

I'm binding a type my_type

```cpp
py::class_<my_type, std::shared_ptr<my_type>>(m, "MyType")
        .def("__repr__", [](const my_type& o){return fmt::format("MyType: {}", o);});
```

as well as a std::vector<my_type> with

```cpp
py::bind_vector<std::vector<my_type>>(m, "MyTypeVector");
```

How can/should I declare MyTypeVector's `__repr__` method here if I want its output to be a sequence of `MyType.__repr__` for each object in the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JesseC helped a lot, but someone pointed out a weakness in that approach: it forces either the classes to define their own operator<<, or the programmer to define it in the bindings (which is a problem if the class has already defined an operator<<, but doesn't match what he or she wants as their `__repr__` output). The core library shouldn't need to be aware that it's getting binded and therefore shouldn't be forced to implement such method.
To that end, one can modify the operator<< on the std::vector to:

```
template<class T>
inline std::string vector_repr(const std::vector<T>& v){
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << "Vector[";

    auto py_vector = py::cast(v);
    const auto separator = ", ";
    const auto* sep = "";

    for( auto obj : py_vector ){
        out << sep << obj.attr("__repr__")();
        sep = separator;
    }
    out << "]";

    return out.str();
}
```

along with the binding

```
py::bind_vector<MyTypeVector>(m, "MyTypeVector")
    .def("__repr__", [](const MyTypeVector& v){
             return vector_repr(v);
});
```

Comment: It actually doesn't force a toString() method, just an operator<< for your classes (which do not need to be defined inside the class). We have toString() methods on all our generated code already, which makes using it in operator<< the logical choice, but you could just implement operator<< without toString. Overall, I think having operator<< defined for all your c++ classes is a super-helpful pattern anyway, since it makes logging a breeze.

Comment: I agree that it's good practice to have an operator<<. But in this case the operator<< has to match what you output in '__repr__', which isn't necessarily what you wanted from operator<<. Also, if you're binding a third-party library, you don't want to be forced to go to the insides of it and edit the source code this way.

Comment: But you're right that I misspoke saying it forces a toString() method, I corrected that in my answer

Comment: yeah, it is really matter of design consistency. I want my c++ and python string representations to match. So it doesn't make sense in my case to implement my stringification functions with python dependencies because I want my pure c++ code to be able to use it as well and why involve calls into python for that. If you just care about python, calling repr here makes more sense.
You can also add `operator<<` to third-party libs in your own source without modifying the external source code. Just need to make sure it is in the same namespace as the third party object is.

Comment: Fair, but you might want the python stringification to differ in format. For example if cpp prints "my_type(a=1)", but you want python to print "MyType(a=1)" due to different style guides. Also, if you want to define `__str__` as well as `__repr__`, and have them be different, you can't have them both rely on cpp's operator<<.
I was thinking of the case where the third party has a defined operator<< not printing exactly what you would want. If you add your own operator<< then, it will conflict with theirs, I believe. You would have to edit their source code to delete/modify their definition.

Answer (score 5):

it is actually very simple. `py::bind_vector` is just a wrapper around `class_` so you can add methods to it just like you would add them to a normal class.

In your case you can just do

```
py::bind_vector<std::vector<my_type>>(m, "MyTypeVector")
  .def("__repr__", [](const std::vector<my_type>& v) {// generate your string here;});
```

So for making the string representation, I generally define `toString` methods and the `<<` operator in my c++ classes.

```
class BadData
{
// lots of stuff going on and removed here
    virtual void
    putMembers(std::ostream& out) const
    {
      out << "msg=" << >msg;
      out << ", ";
      out << "stack=" << stack;
    }

    virtual std::string
    toString() const
    {
      std::ostringstream out;
      out << "BadData(";
      putMembers(out);
      out << ")";
      return out.str();
    }
}

inline
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const BadData &item)
{
  stream << item.toString();
  return stream;
}
```

We also have operator<< defined for stl collections

```
template<class T> inline
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v)
{
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << "Vector[";
  if (v.size() > 0) {
    for (auto ii = v.cbegin(); ii != v.cend() -1 ; ++ii) {
      out << *ii << ", ";
    }
    out << v.back();
  }
  out << "]";
  os << out.str();
  return os;
}
```

So once you have all those operators defined, your `__repr__` method can just look like

```
.def("__repr__", [](const std::vector<my_type>& v) {
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << v;
    return stream.str(); 
})
```

or in the case of your custom class, like

```
.def("__repr__", &::my_type::toString)
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse, but what I meant was: what should I use in the body of the lambda where you have  "// generate your string here" to reproduce the __repr__ for each item

Comment: A loop generating a “representation string”..?

Comment: @user2864740, can I generate that "representation string" from the previously defined '__repr__' of MyType?  Or do I have to type them again manually?

Comment: Might want to reword the entire question then: that’s (mostly) about calling a method on a “MyType” Python/proxy object then.

Comment: I suppose I could create a function to generate that string and use it in both MyType's __repr__ and a loop inside MyTypeVector's __repr__, that way there's no code duplication

Comment: I edited to add the method that we are using to generate our `__repr__` values